# Wrong order when parsing value via RegEx

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I want to parse the state of my printer from its website.

here is my code, which is working well expect the order of the results of the while loop:

```
const https = require('https')
const options = {
  hostname: '192.168.178.35',
  port: 443,
  path: '/PRESENTATION/ADVANCED/INFO_PRTINFO/TOP',
  method: 'GET',
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
  
  res.on('data', d => {
    console.log(d)
    let match;
    let rx;
    rx = new RegExp(/(?:MAC-Adresse|Printer Name|Adresse MAC Wi-Fi\/R.seau|Indirizzo MAC Wi-Fi\/rete|Dirección MAC de Wi-Fi\/Red|Endereço MAC de Wi-Fi\/Rede)&nbsp;:<\/span><\/dt><dd class=\"value clearfix\"><div class=\"preserve-white-space\">([a-zA-Z0-9:]*)<\/div>/g);

    while ((match = rx.exec(d)) != null) {
      let mac_string = match[1];
      console.log(mac_string)
    }
    
    let inks = [
      {
        name: 'Cyan',
        inklvl_rx: "IMAGE\/Ink_C\.PNG\' height=\'([0-9]{1,2})\'",
        cartridge_rx: "\\(C\\)&nbsp;\\:<\\/span><\\/dt><dd class=\\\"value clearfix\\\"><div class=\\\"preserve-white-space\\\">([a-zA-Z0-9\\/]*)<\\/div>"
        
      },
      {
        name: 'Black',
        inklvl_rx: "IMAGE\/Ink_K\.PNG\' height=\'([0-9]{1,2})\'",
        cartridge_rx: "\\(BK\\)&nbsp;\\:<\\/span><\\/dt><dd class=\\\"value clearfix\\\"><div class=\\\"preserve-white-space\\\">([a-zA-Z0-9\\/]*)<\\/div>"
      },
      {
        name: 'Magenta',
        inklvl_rx: "IMAGE\/Ink_M\.PNG\' height=\'([0-9]{1,2})\'",
        cartridge_rx: "\\(M\\)&nbsp;\\:<\\/span><\\/dt><dd class=\\\"value clearfix\\\"><div class=\\\"preserve-white-space\\\">([a-zA-Z0-9\\/]*)<\\/div>"
      },
      {
        name: 'Waste',
        inklvl_rx: "IMAGE\/Ink_Waste\.PNG\' height=\'([0-9]{1,2})\'",
        cartridge_rx: "Wartungsbox&nbsp;\\:<\\/span><\\/dt><dd class=\"value clearfix\\\"><div class=\\\"preserve-white-space\\\">([a-zA-Z0-9\\/]*)<\\/div>"
      }
    ];
    
    // read cartridge
    inks.forEach(ink => {
      rx = new RegExp(ink.inklvl_rx, "g");
      while ((match = rx.exec(d)) != null) {
        var ink_string = match[1];
        console.log(ink_string)
      }
      
      rx = new RegExp(ink.cartridge_rx, "g");
      while ((match = rx.exec(d)) != null) {
        var cartridge_string = match[1];
        console.log(cartridge_string)
      }
    })
  })
})

req.on('error', error => {
  console.error(error)
})

req.end()
```

The MAC address which will be parsed in the first while loop will be outputted at last.

Can you explain me why the order of all while loops is different?

Input:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="Author" content="SEIKO EPSON">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>WF-4820 Series</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../COMMON/STYLE.CSS'>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='SCRIPT.JS'></script>
</head>
<body class="contents">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="header-main">Produktstatus</div>
        <div class="section">
            <fieldset class="group no-legend">
                <form target="_top" action="/PRESENTATION/ADVANCED/COMMON/TOP" method="post" id="input_form" name="input_form">
                    <ul class="values">
                        <li class="value clearfix">
                            <select class="select" id="SEL_LANGA" name="SEL_LANGA" onchange="return document.input_form.submit();">
                                <option value="1">English</option>
                                <option value="2">Français</option>
                                <option value="4" selected>Deutsch</option>
                                <option value="3">Italiano</option>
                                <option value="5">Español</option>
                                <option value="6">Português</option>
                                <option value="7">Nederlands</option>
                                <option value="8">Русский</option>
                                <option value="12">Norsk</option>
                                <option value="13">Svenska</option>
                                <option value="14">Suomi</option>
                                <option value="15">polski</option>
                                <option value="16">Čeština</option>
                                <option value="17">Magyar</option>
                                <option value="18">Dansk</option>
                                <option value="19">Türkçe</option>
                                <option value="20">Ελληνικά</option>
                                <option value="21">Slovensky</option>
                                <option value="22">Română</option>
                                <option value="23">Україна</option>
                                <option value="10">繁體中文</option>
                                <option value="11">简体中文</option>
                                <option value="9">한국어</option>
                            </select>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </form>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="group no-legend">
                <fieldset class="group">
                    <legend>Druckerstatus</legend>
                    <ul class="values">
                        <li class="value clearfix">
                            <div class="preserve-white-space">Verfügbar</div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="values">
                        <li class="value clearfix">
                            <div class="preserve-white-space"></div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="group">
                    <legend>Scannerstatus</legend>
                    <ul class="values">
                        <li class="value clearfix">
                            <div class="preserve-white-space">Verfügbar</div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="values">
                        <li class="value clearfix">
                            <div class="preserve-white-space"></div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </fieldset>
                <div id="ELSE_STATUS">
                    <fieldset class="group">
                        <legend>Anderer Status</legend>
                        <ul class="values">
                            <li class="value clearfix">
                                <div class="preserve-white-space">
                                    <noscript>Aktivieren Sie die JavaScript-Einstellung des Browsers.</noscript>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="value clearfix">
                                <div class="preserve-white-space" id="ELSE_STATUS_WARNING_RESTART">Die Einstellung, die einen Neustart erfordert, wurde geändert. Schalten Sie das Gerät aus und wieder ein.</div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                //
                HideElseStatus(); //-->
                </script>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="information-last clearfix ">
                <ul class="inksection">
                    <li class='tank'>
                        <div class='tank'>
                            <img class='color' src='../../IMAGE/Ink_K.PNG' height='48' style=''>
                        </div>
                        <div class='clrname'>BK</div>
                    </li>
                    <!--
                    -->
                    <li class='tank'>
                        <div class='tank'>
                            <img class='color' src='../../IMAGE/Ink_C.PNG' height='48' style=''>
                        </div>
                        <div class='clrname'>C</div>
                    </li>
                    <!--
                    -->
                    <li class='tank'>
                        <div class='tank'>
                            <img class='color' src='../../IMAGE/Ink_M.PNG' height='48' style=''>
                        </div>
                        <div class='clrname'>M</div>
                    </li>
                    <!--
                    -->
                    <li class='tank'>
                        <div class='tank'>
                            <img class='color' src='../../IMAGE/Ink_Y.PNG' height='48' style=''>
                        </div>
                        <div class='clrname'>Y</div>
                    </li>
                    <!--
                    -->
                    <li class='tank'>
                        <div class='tank'>
                            <img class='color' src='../../IMAGE/Ink_Waste.PNG' height='47' style=''>
                        </div>
                        <div class='mbicn'>
                            <img src='../../IMAGE/Icn_Mb.PNG' height='18' width='18'>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <fieldset class="group no-legend">
                <dl class="values">
                    <dt class="key">
                        <span class="key">Schwarz (BK)&nbsp;:</span>
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="value clearfix">
                        <div class="preserve-white-space">405/405XL</div>
                    </dd>
                    <dt class="key">
                        <span class="key">Cyan (C)&nbsp;:</span>
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="value clearfix">
                        <div class="preserve-white-space">405/405XL</div>
                    </dd>
                    <dt class="key">
                        <span class="key">Magenta (M)&nbsp;:</span>
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="value clearfix">
                        <div class="preserve-white-space">405/405XL</div>
                    </dd>
                    <dt class="key">
                        <span class="key">Gelb (Y)&nbsp;:</span>
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="value clearfix">
                        <div class="preserve-white-space">405/405XL</div>
                    </dd>
                    <dt class="key">
                        <span class="key">Wartungsbox&nbsp;:</span>
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="value clearfix">
                        <div class="preserve-white-space">T6715</div>
                    </dd>
                </dl>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="group no-legend">
                <fieldset class="group">
                    <legend>Kassette 1</legend>
                    <dl class="values">
                        <dt class="key">
                            <span class="key">Papiergröße&nbsp;:</span>
                        </dt>
                        <dd class="value clearfix">
                            <div class="preserve-white-space">A4 210 x 297 mm</div>
                        </dd>
                        <dt class="key">
                            <span class="key">Papiertyp&nbsp;:</span>
                        </dt>
                        <dd class="value clearfix">
                            <div class="preserve-white-space">Normalpapier</div>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                </fieldset>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="group no-legend">
                <dl class="values">
                    <dt class="key">
                        <span class="key">Epson Connect-Status&nbsp;:</span>
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="value clearfix">
                        <div class="preserve-white-space">Nicht registriert</div>
                    </dd>
                    <dt class="key">
                        <span class="key">Epson Connect-eMail-Adresse&nbsp;:</span>
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="value clearfix">
                        <div class="preserve-white-space"></div>
                    </dd>
                </dl>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="group no-legend">
                <dl class="values">
                    <dt class="key">
                        <span class="key">Firmware&nbsp;:</span>
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="value clearfix">
                        <div class="preserve-white-space">04.51.SH20KA</div>
                    </dd>
                    <dt class="key">
                        <span class="key">Stammzertifikat-Version&nbsp;:</span>
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="value clearfix">
                        <div class="preserve-white-space">02.02</div>
                    </dd>
                    <dt class="key">
                        <span class="key">Seriennummer&nbsp;:</span>
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="value clearfix">
                        <div class="preserve-white-space">SDFKOPE2D</div>
                    </dd>
                    <dt class="key">
                        <span class="key">Netzwerk-MAC-Adresse&nbsp;:</span>
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="value clearfix">
                        <div class="preserve-white-space">XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX</div>
                    </dd>
                </dl>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="group no-legend">
                <dl class="values">
                    <dt class="key odd">Datum und Zeit&nbsp;:</dt>
                    <dd class="value odd">
                        <div class="clearfix">06-02-2021 15:28 UTC+00:00</div>
                    </dd>
                </dl>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="group no-legend">
                <dl class="values">
                    <dt class="key">
                        <span class="key">Administratorname/Kontaktinformationen&nbsp;:</span>
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="value clearfix">
                        <div class="preserve-white-space"></div>
                    </dd>
                </dl>
            </fieldset>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            //
            initialize(); //-->
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <form action="" method='get' id='refresh_form'>
                <div>
                    <input type='hidden' value='' name='tm'>
                </div>
            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            //
            document.getElementById('refresh_form').tm.value = new Date().getTime(); //-->
            </script>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="footer_button" align="left">
                        <ul class="buttons">
                            <li class="button">
                                <button type="button" class="button" onclick="document.getElementById('refresh_form').submit(); return false;">Aktualisieren</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td class="footer_license" align="right">
                        <a class="license" target="_blank" href="/PRESENTATION/ADVANCED/LICENSE/TOP">Softwarelizenzen</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```